# Difficulties in using jacobian of torch.autograd.functional

Tags: python, pytorch

I am solving PDE, so I need the jacobian matrix of the residual with respect to variables.

Here is my code

```
import torch
from torch.autograd.functional import jacobian
def get_residual (pgnew, swnew):
    residual_w  = 5*(swnew-swold)+T_w*((pgnew[2:,:,:]-pgnew[1:-1,:,:])-(pc[2:,:,:]-pc[1:-1,:,:])) - T_w*((pgnew[1:-1,:,:]-pgnew[0:-2,:,:])-(pc[1:-1,:,:]-pc[0:-2,:,:]))
    residual_g  = 5*((1-swnew)-(1-swold))+T_g*(pgnew[2:,:,:]-pgnew[1:-1,:,:]) - T_g*(pgnew[1:-1,:,:]-pgnew[0:-2,:,:])
    residual    = torch.ravel(torch.column_stack((residual_w,residual_g)))
    return residual

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dt       = 0.01
    T_w      = 10 
    T_g      = 12
    swnew     = torch.zeros(3, 1, 1, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float64)   
    swold     = torch.ones(3, 1, 1, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float64)     
    pgnew     = 2*torch.ones(5, 1, 1, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float64)
    pc        = 3*torch.ones(5, 1, 1, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float64)
    

    unknown  = torch.ravel(torch.column_stack((pgnew[1:-1,:,:],swnew)))
    
    residual = get_residual(pgnew, swnew)
    print('Check Jacobian \n', jacobian(get_residual, unknown))
```

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jacobian-matrix-in-pytorch/);
however, it shows an error, namely,

> get_residual() missing 1 required positional argument: 'swnew',

so I change it to

```
print('Check Jacobian \n', jacobian(get_residual(pgnew, swnew),unknown)
```

Then it shows 'Tensor' object is not callable'

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the `jacobian` a `tuple` as second argument, containing the arguments of `get_residual`:

```
print('Check Jacobian \n', jacobian(get_residual, (pgnew, swnew)))
```

(You may need to make sure that they have the shape you want etc.)

Comment: I made a unknown, I want the residual to be differentiated by the element of the unknown

Comment: @Miraboreasu It still needs two variables...

Comment: I see I need the variable to be combined alternatively, so I need also to change the input of my function get_residual?

Comment: You may consider passing a single variable and do the combination yourself. Would that be feasible? Or you do the combination inside of `get_residual`?!

Comment: Inside ```get_residual``` still needs two inputs of this function right? DIdn't get it